# Panels Page Title CSS?

Tags: panels, theming, 7

I have created a Panels Page but can't find out how and where to put the class for the title?
Right now it uses the core Page Title CSS but I wan't every Panels Page Title to be unique.

Edit: I've noticed that this is the way for all my panels. I can't seem to be able to set a CSS Class to Pane Titles at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you have set panel title like this

[image: title-override]

you can use the class "pane-title" to write the css.

[image: class-]

Comment: Thanks! I noticed that I've already been doing some css styling using pane-title as class.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7 Panels, you can add unique class to your pages. Using page class you can add CSS to your Page Title

[image]

Comment: This method didn't do it for me. It changed the class for the Page Panel area but after this code
`<h1 class="title" id="page-title">My Example Panel Page</h1>` so I got no new class for the page where I wanted.